# How can i make windows 10 boot loader load first then bitlocker

Tags: windows, boot, encryption, bootloader, bitlocker

**I create Windows 10 dual boot installation**

*windows 10 (1)* `[ ENCRYPTED ]` ||  *windows 10 (2)*

I encrypted my C: Drive on my `windows 10 (1)` installation and when I restart my machine bitlocker want's me to put the password in -- sometimes I don't want to boot to `windows 10 (1)` encrypted drive i just want to boot to `windows 10 (2)` without putting bitlocker password.

Is it possible to make boot loader load first to select the OS then depending on the OS bitlocker asks for the password?

For example:

This what happening
PC Starting > Bitlocker Screen > Bootloader Chose a OS to boot from

I need it like:

PC Starting >  Bootloader Chose a OS to boot from > If the OS have Bitlocker enabled display Bootloader Chose a OS to boot from.

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to use Bitlocker for that method. You COULD create a secondary drive/partition that you encrypt that you store the user profiles on. However, I'd guess Windows may have trouble accessing the drive early enough to get the files when it needs them for logon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitlocker is actually integrated inside the Windows boot-loader and always gets activated FIRST before the OS selection is shown.

As far as I know the only way around that is to use another (non-Microsoft) bootloader that in turns calls the Windows bootloader.

That may mean boot from another disk first, which holds the 3rd party bootloader (most people would use **grub**, the bootloader also used by Linux), which then calls either bootloader of Windows 1 or Bootloader of Windows 2.
Another typical scenario is dual-booting between Linux and Windows, using the Linux bootloader (grub) as the main loader, which in turn calls the Windows loader when needed (and you can have multiple Windows loaders from the Linux bootloader too).

You might want to look into the ["Plop"](https://www.plop.at/en/home.html) bootlader. Plop is specifically designed for all sort of weird boot-loader scenarios where the normal bootloader provided by the OS isn't quite able to make things happen as you would like.
Plop can also (in some cases) work around some limitations of your Bios.

PS. I'm not affiliated with Plop. Just a happy user of that particular piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 on bitlocker screen and select a different OS.